# Basic SCons example throwing `Do not know how to make File target `helloworld' error

Tags: c, build, windows-10, scons

I'm trying to follow [this](https://github.com/SCons/scons/wiki/SconsTutorial1) tutorial to build a simple C program using SCons. I created a file called `SConstruct` which contains the following:

```
env = Environment() # construction environment
env.Program(target='helloworld', source=['helloworld.c']) # build targets
```

I created a file called `helloworld.c` which includes the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    printf("Hello World.");
}
```

Then I tried building from Powershell as follows:

`scons helloworld`

Unfortunately I got the following output

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: building terminated because of errors.
scons: *** Do not know how to make File target `helloworld` (..\scons-tutorial\helloworld). Stop.
```

I followed the steps in the tutorial very closely, so I'm not sure what else I can do at this point. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

The error message is because there is no `helloworld` target. Yes, you said `target='helloworld'`, but SCons is making it easy for the the SConscripts to be portable, and the  prefixes and suffix extensions are assumed to be added on during the build when the platform can be resolved.

This means that on Windows, where the `PROGSUFFIX` (program suffix) is `.exe`, you should type `scons helloworld.exe` to build the target. Note that all build output filepaths are implicitly targets.

If you wanted to make the `scons helloworld` a platform portable command for your build, you could use an alias:

```
helloworld_nodes = env.Program(target='helloworld', source=['helloworld.c']) # build targets
env.Alias('helloworld_app', helloworld_nodes)
```

now you could type `scons helloworld_app` on any platform and it would build the helloworld binary.

Comment: Above wouldn't work on windows.  You'll need to save the returned Node from env.Program() and use that as the second argument to env.Alias().

Comment: ahh you're right, I updated to pass the node

Comment: Just as a wrap-up: if you let SCons do the target selection (as when running "`scons`" or "`scons .`") there is no issue.  It's if you try to specify a target by name that you have to spell it out correctly for the platform. Added a quick note to that tutorial on the wiki to perhaps avoid others falling into that hole.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the instructions in Section 2.1 of [this link](https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#idp105548891449168) were more accurate. It suffices to have the following in the SConstruct file:

```
Program(target='helloworld', source='helloworld.c') # build targets
```

Running a simple `scons` from the command line then works.

Comment: In this case, the simple `scons` would have worked for the initial example as well.